# How to know my query has an error or not without changing the real data in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I need to make a system to check whether my update query is error or not without change any rows in database is it possible?

I am using c# asp.net and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 5):

1. Start a transaction
2. Run your statement
3. Check for errors
4. Rollback your transaction

Answer (score 1):

not sure I understood your question, so I guess...

I would execute the command inside a Transaction and call rollback instead of commit so the code is executed, in case of errors `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` would throw the exception and in any case following `transaction.RollBack()` would prevent any change to be persisted in the database.